# Editar layout padrão do ErroTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Implementei a interface *IDataErrorInfo*, que está funcionando conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: Error template]

Não criei meu *ErrorTemplate*, o que está sendo usado é o padrão do .NET.

Gostaria de saber se existe em  algum lugar o código XAML desse error template, pois minha intenção é criar meu próprio error template baseado nele.

Já procurei na MSDN e tentei utilizar o WPF Tree Visualizer, mas não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicar detalhadamente como criar/alterar um *template* não é fácil de fazê-lo aqui.

Deixo dois exemplos que eu utilizo:

- **RedBorderOnError** - Aplica uma borda vermelha e mostra um *tooltip* com a mensagem de erro quando se coloca o rato sobre ele.

  ```
  <Style x:Key="RedBorderOnError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                     Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
          </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  ```
- **RedTextOnError** - Aplica a cor vermelha ao Foreground e mostra um *tooltip* com a mensagem de erro quando se coloca o rato sobre ele.

  ```
  <Style x:Key="RedTextOnError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                      <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                          <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                      </Border>
                  </DockPanel>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                     Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
          </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  ```

Atribua o *Style* ao *TextBox* desta forma:

```
<TextBox ........
    Style="{StaticResource RedBorderOnError}"
    .....
    ....../>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!